# Properties of wedge product

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove 
a) $\omega \wedge \eta =(-1)^{kl}\eta\wedge\omega, \omega$ is $k$-tensor and $\eta$ is $l$-tensor.
b)$f^*(\omega \wedge \eta)=f^*(\omega)\wedge f^*(\eta)$ where $f:V\rightarrow W$ is linear transformation and $f^*:Ten^k(W)\rightarrow Ten^k(V)$.

Comment: Was it - how much? - five hours ago that I voted to close this question as off-topic because of lack of any attempt of solution?

Comment: Three hours ago, [actually](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817283/simple-properties-of-wedge-product).